# Button doesn't show background drawable

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, styles

I'm quite a noob at programming, I've been following some tutorials and I changed something in the styles or color or something and now I have the issue that when I'm trying to create button, it starts off with a specific color and for this, it doesn't let me set a background resource that I've done before.

How can I make that the button shows this drawable?

this is the xml (although this happens in all my layouts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_black_background">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_image_search"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="User name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_profile_image_search" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_full_name_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Full name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_search"     />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/follow_btn_search"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_black_background"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:padding="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_full_name_search" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the drawable that I want to use

[image: drawable for button]

### This is my button with the background set but not showing

[image: button with brown color and background not showing]

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button_black_background"/>
```

these are my colors

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#721100</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3F0101</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF5AB0</color>
<color name="colorTextPrimary">#212121</color>
<color name="colorTextSecondary">#757575</color>
</resources>
```

and these are my styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>
```

Comment: Attach your xml for the layout please

Comment: Sure my friend, now the XML is there. Notice that in the first constraint layout the drawable does appear, but in the button, it doesn't. I'm quite lost with this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Button from package androidx. This code,

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/follow_btn_search"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_black_background"
    android:text="Follow"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_full_name_search" />
```

Comment: Yes! this was the solution, thank you very much.
Does this mean that all the "default" Button always uses the Colors.xml file?

Comment: Yes. The advantage of AppCompatButton you can set the appearance of the button based on the state.

Answer (score 0):

In root of constraint layout setting same drawable .pls remove from.